# Finding the average from an array

Tags: javascript, function, average

I'm here learning javascript. And I'm trying to make a function that will take in all the gpa of each student, find the average and console log it.

```
var stuObj = [{
        name: " Alexandra Williams",
        address: {
            address: " 297 S Wilton Drive, Somewhere AR"
        },
        gpa: [2.5 + ', ' + 3.5 + ', ' + 4.0]
    },

    {
        name: "Kallie Johnson",
        address: {
            address: " 84B NNE 332 Street', Queens NY"
        },
        gpa: [2.3 + ', ' + 3.7 + ', ' + 4.0]
    }
];
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: I'm actually lost on how to do it. I'm guessing I should use a loop to go thru the array. and I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: hmm, may be start by adding a blank function

Comment: What part specifically are you having trouble with? We can't help you if you just come here without anything.

Comment: sorry @jhn thats really all i have, I am just learning javascript on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are constructing your arrays the wrong way:

   ```
   gpa: [2.3, 3.7, 4.0] // no need for string concatenation here
   ```
2. Sum up all the values using a simple `for` loop
3. Divide the sum by the `length` of the array